# Nhibernate: Foreign key must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key

Tags: nhibernate, orm

I'm confused with this situation. Having these two classes:

```
public class TxType {
    public TxType()
    {
        Payments = new List<Payment>();
    }
    public string TxTypeId { get; set; }
    public string TxCode { get; set; }
    public IList<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; } }

public class Payment {
    public Payment() { }
    public  string Trn { get; set; }
    public  TxType TxTypeId { get; set; }
    public  string TxCode { get; set; }        
    public  System.Nullable<decimal> Amount { get; set; }
    public  System.Nullable<System.DateTime> DateStamp { get; set; } }
```

TxType table have two PK (TxTypeId, TxCode),  and both are FK in Payment Table.
These are my mappings:

```
  <class name="TxType" table="TxType" lazy="false" >
    <composite-id>
      <key-property name="TxTypeId" column="TxTypeId" />
      <key-property name="TxCode" column="TxCode" />
    </composite-id>
    <property name="Description">
      <column name="Description" sql-type="nvarchar" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <bag name="Payments" inverse="true" cascade="none">
      <key>
        <column name="TxTypeId" />
        <column name="TxCode" />
      </key>      
      <one-to-many class="MyProject.Nhibernate.Repository.Payment" not-found="ignore" />
    </bag>
  </class>

  <class name="Payment" table="Payment" lazy="false" >
    <id name="Trn">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one insert="false" update="false" lazy="false" name="TxTypeId">
      <column name="TxTypeId" sql-type="varchar" not-null="false" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="TxTypeId">
      <column name="TxTypeId" sql-type="varchar" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <many-to-one insert="false" update="false" lazy="false" name="TxCode">
      <column name="TxCode" sql-type="varchar" not-null="false" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="TxCode">
      <column name="TxCode" sql-type="varchar" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="Amount">
      <column name="Amount" sql-type="decimal" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="DateStamp">
      <column name="DateStamp" sql-type="datetime" not-null="false" />
    </property>    
  </class>
```

And I'm stuck with this error:
Foreign key (FKF4FA0208CDBA724F:Payment [TxTypeId])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (TxType [TxTypeId, TxCode]).

Thanks!

Okay, i figured out by adding these lines in Payment mapping:

```
<many-to-one name="TxType" class="MyProject.Nhibernate.Repository.TxType" insert="false" update="false" lazy="false" >
  <column name="TxTypeId" sql-type="varchar" not-null="false" />
  <column name="TxCode" sql-type="varchar" not-null="false" />
</many-to-one>
```

Thanks!

Comment: not axactly an answer to the question but if you set `<bag name="Payments" inverse="true">` and `<many-to-one name="TxType" insert="false" update="false">` you are not able to add any payments to transactions

Answer (score 1):

Your id property must be only one. That is, if your table has a composite primary key, you should create a class for mapping to these columns. Remember, the Get/Load methods only take a single parameter for the id, not many.